Remove these html names from message in dataweave
How do I remove this from message which I could only describe as html names like &amp; or &lt;
Can I do it without using replace function ?
Sample message:
{
    "message": "Hello world &amp; welcome"
}

Expected output:
{
    "message": "Hello world & welcome"
}


Check if approach 2 helps you. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=001116189&type=1 @Nadeem

The solutions in that link should work however note that the first one uses a fixed list of entities. I wrote a solution which doesn't require to fix the values in the code. Also those scripts expect a specific input format that needs to be adapted to user requirements.

@karthik: I tried the 2nd approach. Its adding entities rather than removing them.

Fortunately, they were xml entities. So, I went with your solution @aled

If you are lucky those are XML entities. There are 5 XML entities vs hundreds of HTML entities.
There is no built-in function in DataWeave at this time to resolve XML or HTML entities. I wrote a pure DataWeave solution using replace() where the entities are not fixed in the code, giving flexibility to modify the list of entities as needed. This approach also works for any arbitrary list of strings that needs to be replaced. A little trick is to use reduce() to apply replace() for each entity instead of using to accumulate values.
Also I used the update operator to update a specific key of the message.
Script:
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var xmlEntities={
    "&amp;": "&",
    "&lt;": "<",
    "&gt;": ">",
    "&apos;": "'",
    "&quot;": "\""
}

fun replaceEntities(s: String, entities)=
    entriesOf(entities) reduce ((item, acc = s) -> acc replace item.key with(item.value))
---
payload update {
    case m at .message -> replaceEntities(m, xmlEntities)
}

Input:
{
  "message": "Hello world &amp; welcome"
}

Output:
{
  "message": "Hello world & welcome"
}

